# operation with integer: result is only zero - Java

Tags: java

I have to do an operation with integers, very simple:

a=b/c*d

where all the variables are integer, but the result is ZERO whatever is the value of the parameters. I guess that it's a problem with the operation with this type of data (int).

I solved the problem converting first in float and then in integer, but I was wondering if there is a better method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/` operator, when used with integers, does integer division which I suspect is not what you want here.  In particular, `2/5` is zero.

The way to work around this, as you say, is to cast one or more of your operands to e.g. a `float`, and then turn the resulting floating point value back into an integer using `Math.floor`, `Math.round` or `Math.ceil`.  This isn't really a bad solution; you have a bunch of integers but you really do want a floating-point calculation.  The output might not be an integer, so it's up to you to specify how you want to convert it back.

More importantly, I'm not aware of any syntax to do this that would be more concise and readable than (for example):

```
a = Math.round((float)b / c * d)
```

Comment: ok, the other solution (first moltiplication, then division) works sometimes, but you convinced me that in these cases there is nothing "bad" in converting in float

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can reorder the expression so division is performed last:

```
a = (b*d)/c
```

Be careful that `b*d` won't ever be large enough to overflow an `int`. If it might be, you could cast one of them to `long`:

```
a = (int)(((long)b*d)/c)
```

Comment: If you're going to cast anyway, why not cast to a float to get floating-point division *and* have the luxury of specifying how you want a non-integer value converted back to int?

Comment: Because floating point calculations are slower, and they lose precision with large values.